# Dynamic UITableView inside static cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've read some threads regarding static & dynamic cells incompatibility, but I'm wondering if there's some workaround for my case.

I have a static table (handled by a `UITableViewController`). I put a dynamic table inside one of its cells. Delegate & datasource is the `UITableViewController` for both tables, and it works pretty well as long as the number of rows for the inner dynamic table is less than the static one. When the dynamic table has more cells than the static one, I get an `index i beyond bounds` exception.

I'm assuming somehow the total number of cells is statically defined and shared by both tables, but can't really understand what's exactly happening. Anybody faced a similar problem and found a workaround?

**EDIT**

Here's my `numberOfRowsInSection` method. In every method of my delegate/datasource, I check wether the calling table is the dynamic one (_tableOptions) or the static (in which case, I call to parent's method).

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == _tableOptions) {
        // I return here the number of rows for the dynamic inner table
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == _tableOptions) {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cellOptions";

        CellOptions *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        // Doing some stuff with my cell... 

        return cell;

    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us code about the datasource.

Comment: can you paste the code you have written in cell configure method.

Comment: Thanks @KudoCC, I put some code that hopefully illustrates how I deal with two tables pointing the same controller.

Comment: I need the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` implementation and details about the array which is beyond bounds.

Comment: @KudoCC Just updated my answer. I don't have control over the array that causes the problem, my guess is that is the array that `UITableViewController` uses to stores static viewcells.

Comment: @ssantos Perhaps you are right. So You use storyboard's static cell? I think on the condition you should implement your static cell manually instead of calling its `super` method.

Comment: @KudoCC yes I do. As far as I know, you're not supposed to manually instantiate static cells, that's actually the point of storyboards static cells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a question of compatibility. If you opt to implement programmatic control functions for static UITableViews then you have to be sure that you're not conflicting with how they're defined in the storyboard.

For example if you implement this function for a UITableView with static cells

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return 5;
}
```

but you've only added 3 static cells for the given view and controller in the storyboard then Xcode cannot simply create 2 more static cells from nothing. I think that the closest thing to a workaround for you is to add another UITableViewController for the table with dynamic cells. You can instantiate the new controller in the current controller that you're using without presenting its view on the screen. Then you can assign the UITableView that has dynamic cells to be the new UITableViewController's tableView property. Likewise, assign the delegate and datasource properties of the UITableView to be the new controller.

**EDIT:** After seeing the code I do know of one possible workaround. You can leverage the number of sections to trick the UITableViewController into doing what you want.

You can use the code below to add arbitrary number of cells to the dynamic view because you're adding the cells to the dynamic table's second section but at the same time setting the number of cells in the static table's second section to 0. The key is that you **MUST** add the max number of cells to the second section of the static table in the storyboard. These will be dummy cells that are never displayed.

In the following image you can see that I set the second section of my static table to be 10 cells and in the code I am able to return up to 10 cells for the `dynamic` tableview.

[image]

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == dynamic)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == dynamic)
    {
        if (section == 1)
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (section == 0)
        {
            return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == dynamic) {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"sample";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.row]];

        // Doing some stuff with my cell...

        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

You can remove the section headers by implementing this function to clean it up:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}
```

After removing the headers for the sections you get exactly what you're trying to accomplish. There are 10 cells in the `dynamic` table inside of the third cell of the static table.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Actually I return a different value depending on which table is `tableView`. I suppose having a different datasource/delegate for each table should work, but still can't understand why can't I use a single controller for both tables.

Comment: Oh thats interesting. Seeing the code made the issue more clear. I don't know the underlying reason this happens but I do have a workaround, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I did something like that without even using sections, adding n empty cells to the end of the static table, and programmatically hiding them. While it works, the number of dynamic cells is variable (I can't grant it will be less than 10 or 50), so I don't think this is a reliable solution :(

Comment: I think your best choice is to not use a workaround here, it is likely to come back and bite you when Apple makes changes later. You will probably save yourself a lot of trouble if you use my original suggestion to create a second tableview controller.