# Implement a dynamic table within a static table view (cell)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

So basically I have implemented a **static table** so far and at the very bottom, I want to add another **dynamic table** for the participant list of the event. Check out the screenshot here:

[image: Screenshot of my Xcode project]

My problem now is, that I'm not able to setup the dynamic table with its own class which is placed in the last static table view cell. You can check out the red marked squares in the screenshot. My actual plan was to give the dynamic table its own class and then retrieve the participant list as an array and setup the numberOfRowsInSection according to the count of the array etc.

Do you guys have an idea how I can implement that within a static table? Basically, how can I add that dynamic table at the bottom, including later then endless scrolling?

I've tried this post so far but it didn't completely help me: [Dynamic UITableView inside static cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777878/dynamic-uitableview-inside-static-cell)
I'll add my solution below.

Your help would appreciated a lot!

Kind regards
Matt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic UITableView inside static cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777878/dynamic-uitableview-inside-static-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay thank you rMickeyD for your tip. I used it partially and implemented it. You can see the result on this screenshot here:

[image: Storyboard]

Adding to this I set the height of the cell in the static table with a prepareToSegue to the array of the guests.count * 44 for the cell height in the right.

Code for the static table view (left):

```
import UIKit
class EventDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var attendeesArrayFromDatabase = ["Kathi", "Cansin", "Tyrone", "Manuel", "Stavros", "Christoph", "Maria", "Aditya", "Kathi", "Cansin", "Tyrone", "Manuel", "Stavros", "Christoph", "Maria", "Aditya"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            let height:CGFloat = CGFloat(attendeesArrayFromDatabase.count * 44)
            return height
        }
        return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    // MARK: Navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destViewController : EventPeopleJoinedContainerTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! EventPeopleJoinedContainerTableViewController

        destViewController.attendeesArray = attendeesArrayFromDatabase
    }
}
```

and the right tableview for the dynamic table:

```
import UIKit
class EventPeopleJoinedContainerTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var attendeesArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return attendeesArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("personJoined", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        //Create a label with the name of a person from array attendeesArray
        let attendeeNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 70, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height))
        attendeeNameLabel.font = cell.textLabel?.font.fontWithSize(14.0)
        attendeeNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        attendeeNameLabel.text = attendeesArray[indexPath.row] as? String

        //Create a image view for the profile picture of the guest
        let attendeeImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 7, width: 30, height: 30))
        attendeeImageView.layer.cornerRadius = attendeeImageView.frame.size.width/2
        attendeeImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        attendeeImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        attendeeImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        attendeeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "profilPicDummy")

        cell.contentView.addSubview(attendeeNameLabel)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(attendeeImageView)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's a real reason to have the top portion be a table as well, the easiest solution is going to be to make the top portion a table header view and just use a dynamic table.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewController.  Then place two ContainerViewControllers inside of the ViewController.  Create segues to 2 separate tableViewcontrollers using embed. One to the static tableview and one to the dynamic tableview.  This way you could have a static table on top and a dynamic one below.

Comment: hey rMickeyD, thank you for your reply. I've found the solution, you helped me with your post.